# How to generate UML Activity diagrams from code in NetBeans?

Tags: java, netbeans, uml

I have installed `UML Netbeans` plugin for reverse engineering to automatically convert my Java code into `UML`.  But my question is, how can I draw the activity diagram using the `Netbeans` plugin?  Whenever I select activity, sequence , collaboration or any other `UML` diagram instead of class diagram, still only class diagram is created. It doesn't create the desired `UML` diagram.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There was a powerful UML plugin in NetBeans several years before, but there is not now. They had some problems with license. But you could install free 30-day Visual Paradigm (version from professional up) and create classes diagrams there. That is what I already had to do having the same task in 2014.
Enterprise architect has same possibilities. But VP has free version that you can use after 30 days. Now VP again can be connected to NetBeans. https://netbeans.org/features/uml/. But the VP license remains to be your problem. And the plugin creators promise only code generation, no back engineering.

EasyUML is the free UML plugin for NetBeans now. Class diagrams only. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7pq2fZYPpwo.

Also you can install Eclipse and create diagrams there. Eclipse has rich possibilities for UML. https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/uml-java-generator. Or more simple: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0Zlh56mTS6c.

And notice, the class diagram is the only strict UML diagram, that can be converted to code and back. (with some limitations, too). For other diagrams it is simply not possible. Oh, it is possible to create something that is a correct diagram, but you can do it in many ways and the result diagram will show only some details of the code and surely they will be not necessary details for which you would like to create a diagram.